# How to go from one view to another view in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I create Login page include (username & password & login button)

I want when to fill text field username and password if right user and password go on another page else if to be wrong give me one alert.

this is my code:

```
#import "Detail.h"

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSString *name;
}
@synthesize Username,Password;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {

    NSString *a = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.102/mamal/login.php?u=%@&p=%@",Username.text,Password.text];
    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:a]];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    if ([url isEqualToString:@"0"]) //this is wrong user & password
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"WRONG" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dissmis" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        name = @"Mohammad";
    }
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"Mohammad"] , [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Segue"]) {
        Detail *det = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

but dosent work!!!  I want only right user & password go on next page

Answer (score 3):

You have to make triggerless segue to perform this operation. Make triggerless segue from storyboard and fire it when your username and password is right.

To create a triggerless segue, start control+dragging the segue from the containing view controller icon in the scene dock at the bottom of the scene. Drag to the destination scene like normal, and pick the segue type. Select the segue, and in the inspector, choose a segue identifier.

Then call the method [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" sender:nil];
when your condition is true

Comment: From Storyboard, Don't set segue on login button.

Comment: On FirstViewcontoller bottom, there will be viewcontroller icon. Set segue from there to another view controller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use segues I think you are missing the call to actually perform the segue after the line where you set the name

```
name = @"Mohammed"        
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self]
```

Being "mySegue" the identifier of your segue in storyboard.

And then, you probably want to send the new View Controller the name.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
        Detail *det = segue.destinationViewController;
        det.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: my friend this code is right but when I click in login button with wrong user and pass go on next page

Comment: I dont want this!!! I want when to click login button with right user and pass go on next page

Comment: You have to put the performSegueWithIdentifier line wherever you want to make the transition to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Here AuditViewController is segue name

you need to call class like this in storyboard

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AuditViewController" sender:self];
```

**Edit**

*Check Condition*

```
- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {

    NSString *a = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.102/mamal/login.php?u=%@&p=%@",Username.text,Password.text];
    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:a]];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    if ([url isEqualToString:@"0"]) //this is wrong user & password
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"WRONG" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dissmis" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        name = @"Mohammad";
        if([name isEqualToString:@"Mohammad"])
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
        //else
            //NSLog(@"Can not Login");
    }
}
```

*prepareForSegue* method call

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Segue"]) 
    {
        Detail *det = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: my friend I run this code but when I fill wrong user & pass and click login button still go on next page

Comment: Yes but at same time you are testing like correct user then navigate else give alert

Comment: sorry my friend I so confused

Comment: You can see code under Edit section. Write that in your .m file. Avoid code above Edit.

Comment: I have two view in storyboard that connect segue (modal) together